# Overwrite an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am new at Java and I am trying to overwrite an array like the following: `{2,7,6,1,9}` to `{9,13,7,10,9}`. So I am trying to add up neighbouring numbers in an array and overwrite the first number with the sum. My code looks like this:

```
int add = numbers[i] + numbers[i+1];
int[] numbersAdd = new int[numbers.length];
i = 1;
int j = 1;
while(j < numbers.length) {
    numbersAdd[j] = add;
    i++;
    j++;
}
```

I get always an `IndexOutofBoundException`.
Can you help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that i has the correct value in `int add = numbers[i] + numbers[i+1];` ?

Comment: Actually I am not sure. But what do you mean exactly? Should I set i = 0;?

Comment: `IndexOutofBoundException` occurs when you try to access index which exceed the length of array. Since you are accessing index `i+1` make sure loop terminating condition is `i < numbers.length - 1`.

Comment: It depends of what do you want to do. But if there must be some code befoure and there there should be some value for `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `add` inside the while loop, and change the starting and ending indexes of `i` and `j`, like:

```
int[] numbersAdd = new int[numbers.length];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while(j < numbers.length - 1) {
    int add = numbers[i] + numbers[i+1];
    numbersAdd[j] = add;
    i++;
    j++;
}
numbersAdd[numbers.length - 1] = numbers[numbers.length - 1];
```

or it can be done using a for-loop:

```
int[] numbersAdd = new int[numbers.length];
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
    numbersAdd[i] = numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1];
}
numbersAdd[numbers.length - 1] = numbers[numbers.length - 1];
```

Comment: @Z.Wo It should work if numbers starts of as `{ 2, 7, 6, 1, 9 }`, and you're printing `numbersAdd` correctly. Can you check the surrounding code?

Answer (score 1):

**I think you want this + - :**

```
public static void diff(int[] numbers) {
        int[] numbersAdd = new int[numbers.length];
        int i=0;
        int j = 0;
        for(int k=0;k<numbers.length;k++)
            numbersAdd[k]=numbers[k];

        while(j < numbers.length-1) {
            numbersAdd[j] = numbers[j] + numbers[j+1];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        for(int k=0;k<numbers.length;k++){
            System.out.print(numbersAdd[k]+" ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I do this

Answer (score 0):

Try doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547320/overwriting-pre-defined-array) (same problem as yours, much simpler answer).

The problem in your code is that on the last iteration i equals (length - 1) so (i+1) equals length and this is invalid index. Change your code to iterate until (length - 2) and it would work.

Comment: int add = numbers[i] + numbers[i+1];
  int[] numbersAdd = new int[numbers.length];
  i = 1;
  int j = 1;
  while(j < numbers.length-2) {
   numbersAdd[j] = add;
   i++;
   j++;
  }

Comment: Try the link I added under "this" in my answer. Your code is "c' like not "java" like. You should use the language features to youe benefit and do this in a single line.